# Check the Node kind in an XML Tree

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsxml

I have constructed an XML tree from an XML file. While constructing I do `initWithKnd:` or `initWithKind: options:` method.

How can I check if a node is of Element or CDATA or ay other kind while tracing the XML tree.

Comment: Am I missing something, or what specifically are you coding this in? JavaScript?

Comment: Sune Rasmussen: The question is tagged as cocoa.

Answer (score 1):

To kind of a NSXMLNode is given by method [kind](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLNode_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002408-BCIDABJC), the return value is from enum [NSXMLNodeKind](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLNode_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSXMLNodeKind).

```
NSXMLNodeKind kind = [node kind];
```

Note that there is no value for CDATA nodes. These become text nodes as the difference between text and CDATA is not preserved in the API.

Answer (score 0):

While tracing the XML tree, one can retrieve the current node, then check if the node kind belongs to element or CDATA or any other kind.

```
NSArray *array = [rootNode children];
NSXMLNode *node = [array objectAtIndex:index];

if([node kind] == NSXMLElementKind )// depending on one's requirement
{
    // doSomething
}
```

Comment: @iSight This just restates my answer.