# How to get attributes from an element in XML

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsxml

I have constructed an XML tree structure of an XML file. I am able to trace the entire tree.

When i want to retrieve the attributes of an element, it is returning as NSXMlNode of  kind `NSXMLAttributeKind`. How can i extract the key value pairs in the attribute node.

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400571

Comment: @Dave this question asks about xml attribute name/value. The other question asked about xml node type. The questions are close, but different.

Comment: @marc_s: The real reason to accept answers is not “incentive”, but so that future readers of the question know what the correct answer to the question is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name and value of a NSXMLNode are given by methods [name](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLNode_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002408-BCIHAJFF) and [stringValue](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLNode_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002408-BCIBGIDA) respectively. For an attribute node, these are the attibute name and value.

The attributes of a NSXMLElement are given by method [attributes](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLElement_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002407-BBCBAACE), or a particular attribute can be accessed by name with method [attributeForName:](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLElement_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002407-BBCFGFBI).

```
NSXMLNode *attr = [element attributeForName: @"data"];
NSString *name = [node name];
NSString *value = [node stringValue];

for( NSXMLNode *node in [element attributes] ) {
    NSString *name = [node name];
    NSString *value = [node stringValue];
}
```